# Send MySQL dynamically

Tags: mysql, sql-server

```
SELECT date M1DATE, time M1TIME 
FROM smart_machine_data 
WHERE m21 LIKE '%ON%'
```

in above query m21 is input parameter name in MySQL store procedure i want to send it dynamically and get related result..
But its not working

Please help me to execute query

Comment: You can not directly specify the table as variable. You have to use prepare statement to achieve this
Please share what you have tried. Post your stored procedure.

Comment: is this sql-server or mysql? note that sql-server is microsoft sql server, BTW, you need to write your query in the body of post not the subject.

Answer (score 0):

```
set @temporary_query =
concat(' select date M1DATE, time M1TIME
         from smart_machine_data
         Where ',m21, ' LIKE '%ON%''
      );

PREPARE stmt from @temporary_query;
EXECUTE stmt ;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt ;
```